# Reading from a vector that was reserved is faster than reading from a non-reserved vector?

Tags: c++, performance

I have the following code

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
struct Point {
 double x, y, z;
};  

const size_t sz = 1'000'000'00;
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
std::vector<Point> points;
points.reserve(sz);
for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
  const double d_val = i;
  points.push_back({d_val, 2.0*d_val, 3*d_val});
}
auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end-start;
std::cout << "filling: " << diff.count() << std::endl;
double tot{0};
for (const auto& p : points)
  tot += p.x + p.y + p.z;
diff = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()-end;
std::cout << "reading: " << diff.count() << std::end;
std::cout << tot;
return 0;
}
```

The results I am getting are around

> filling: 1.78711
>
> reading: 0.233211

However, if I remove **points.reserve(sz);** I get the results

> filling: 8.38341
>
> reading: 1.6607

I get why **filling** takes longer time, but why is **reading** so much slower?

Edit: 
1. I'm using xcode, LLVM 8.0, -O3,

2. I have a "cout << tot" (but did not include it here), so it should not be optimized away.
3. If I delay all the cout's till the end (by saving the time of "filling" in a variable) I still get a difference in "reading" time.

Comment: Did you compile with optimization enabled / in Release mode?

Comment: You're including the time to cout the filling results in the time to read.  This can skew the results significantly.

Comment: Anyways, MCVE and compiler settings please, it's needed to reproduce your findings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you run it for more than one time and take the mean?

Comment: I've run the two different versions several times (pretty much alternating) and I always get results similar to what I posted. I've also tried using -O2 and -O0, still same phenomena.

Comment: Works for me, nothing unexpected: http://ideone.com/B5SqS8 (big difference in filling, no difference in reading.)

Comment: @MikeNakis: That one works for me too. It seems like it's the fact that sz = 10^8 which gives me a big difference, while sz = 10^7 (which you had in the code you are linking to) shows no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but it might be because of the cache effect. When you keep adding data to the vector after reserve(), some of the data may remain in the cache (write-back caching). If you keep adding data without reserve() the data must be relocated and this relocation of the vector data could possibly be done with cache write-through copy. You could test this by warming up the cache first with one read pass and then timing the second read.

Comment: Looks like you are correct, warming up the cache removed the difference.

Comment: I very seriously doubt that you can "warm up" 2.4 GB of memory.

Answer (score 1):

What may be happening is that you are suffering from paging overhead.  That would explain why your results are so difficult to reproduce.

Your vector has 100 million entries, which occupy about 2.4 GB of memory if we assume only 24 bytes per entry.

On the first run, (with `points.reserve(sz);`) all this memory is allocated at once, and your machine probably has enough RAM to satisfy the request, so everything happens as expected down the happy path.

In the second run, (**without** `points.reserve(sz);`) the vector begins small, and keeps growing.  The implementation of `vector` uses an array, so when it wants to resize it allocates a new array, copies the old data, and then frees the old array.  (Instead of doing `realloc()` which would, conceivably, stand some remote chance of happening in-place.)  So, every time the array gets resized, more memory is needed, and the old memory we leave behind is highly fragmented, so it will not be reused unless we first run out of memory, but modern machines tend to hit the paging file before they will admit that they have ran out of memory.

So, by the time the final allocation takes place, you have probably already run out of physical memory, and your logical memory is being paged.  In such a scenario, the copying of the vector during the last resize may happen under conditions of thrashing: before the copy is complete, some of the pages that are part of your vector need to be paged out in order to make room for new pages that will also be part of your vector.

Then, when you try to read the entire vector, each one of those pages needs to be paged back in once, and thus the delay.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable explanation, especially since I don't experience this behavior when sz = 10^7? Do you have any idea why looping over all the elements twice (and only timing the second loop), as suggested by JarkkoL, makes the difference vanish?

Comment: I cannot be sure, but it may be that the first pass makes sure all pages are in physical memory, so the second pass finds them all there.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not use the aggregate value `tot`. The compiler is free to optimise away the entire for loop.

Try this instead:

```
int main()
{
    struct Point {
        double x, y, z;
    };
    const size_t sz = 1'000'000'00;
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<Point> points;
    points.reserve(sz);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        const double d_val = i;
        points.push_back({d_val, 2.0*d_val, 3*d_val});
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end-start;
    std::cout << "filling: " << diff.count() << std::endl;
    double tot{0};
    for (const auto& p : points)
        tot += p.x + p.y + p.z;
    diff = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()-end;

    // <== here
    std::cout << tot << std::endl;
    // <== here

    std::cout << "reading: " << diff.count() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Good guess, but then the difference would have been a lot more pronounced.

Comment: @MikeNakis actually it's fascinating. I have since refactored the entire MCVE to remove all IO skews. gcc seems to generate different code for the 2 cases. clang is 3 times slower with the fragmented vector.

Comment: Hi @RichardHodges, I actually had a "cout << tot" in my code but I removed that row when posting my question.

Comment: Klein: one more vote to close from me, for STILL NOT having posted an MVCE.